# Views that contain UIWebViews take forever to come up, how to alert user?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uialertview

Views that contain UIWebViews take forever to load and for a few seconds it almost seems as though the app has stopped working. I tried inserting a HUD view into the IBAction, but it does not show up. Does anyone have any suggestions for a good way to implement this (btw, the HUD view IS working, it just doesn't show up since it is in the same action as presentModalViewController).

```
-(IBAction)charities {

    [SVProgressHUD showInView:self.view status:@"Loading"];

    Charities *variable = [[Charities alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:variable animated:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I used a NSTimer in the same action as the HUD view and called a function that would bring up the new view. It works perfectly now.

```
-(IBAction)charities {

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0000000000000000000001 target:self selector:@selector(loadCharities) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    [SVProgressHUD showInView:self.view status:@"One sec"];

 }

-(void)loadCharities {

    Charities *variable = [[Charities alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:variable animated:NO];

}
```

Comment: The minimum resolution for an `NSTimer` is around 100ms. If you need something to happen on the next go-around of the run loop, just do `[self performSelector:@selector(loadCharities) withObject:nil afterDelay:0]`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new delegate protocol in `Charities`, and set whatever view from which you are executing this code as the delegate.  Then, from the `UIWebViewDelegate`  `webViewDidFinishLoad:`, call a delegate method that will present the modal view.  This way, you see the loading HUD until the webview is actually ready to be viewed, at which point the view will be presented.